# Spring Boot App with Cglib throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cglib

I am trying to implement the Repository pattern with lazy loading of my entities (I can't use JPA because its a legacy db model). To lazy.load the entities, I am using a cglib MethodInterceptor in order to intercept an entity's getter method, and dynamically hydrate the corresponding property. For example, in the case of an Airport entity, I will lazy load the Terminals property, only if the corresponding getter is called. The whole thing is packaged as a spring boot application.

The repository implementation is given by:

```
@Component
public class AirportsRepository implements Repository<Airport, String> {

    @Autowired
    private AirportMapper airportMapper;
    @Autowired
    private TerminalMapper terminalMapper;

    private List<AirportInterceptor> airportInterceptors = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Airport get(String id) {
        Airport airport = airportMapper.findById(id);
        if(airport != null){
            AirportInterceptor airportInterceptor = new AirportInterceptor(airport, terminalMapper);
            airport = (Airport) Enhancer.create(Airport.class,airportInterceptor);
            this.airportInterceptors.add(airportInterceptor);
            return airport;
        }
        return airport;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Airport entity) {
         //
    }
    @Override
    public void remove(Airport entity) {
         //
    }

    @Override
    public void saveChanges(){
        //

    }

}

public class Airport
{
    // ...
}
```

And the method interceptor:

```
class AirportInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    private TerminalMapper terminalMapper;
    private Airport airport;

    public AirportInterceptor(Airport airport, TerminalMapper terminalMapper){
        this.airport = airport;
        this.terminalMapper = terminalMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        if(method.getName().equals("getTerminals") && method.invoke(obj, args) == null){
            // Hydrate terminals
            List<Terminal> terminals = terminalMapper.findByAirportCode(airport.getId());
            airport.setTerminals(terminals);
        }
        return method.invoke(obj, args);
    }

    public void saveChanges(){
        //airportMapper.update(this.airport);
    }

}
```

However, I am having an issue with the repository code when I call Enhancer.create(), which throws a cryptic exception regarding method toString():

```
Method threw 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.apm.airportservice.entities.Airport$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d0daae41.toString()
```

Comment: One issue I see in your impl (not related to ques), `return method.invoke(obj, args);` statement will run in an infinite loop, if you want to call existing method, use `MethodProxy` object

Answer (score 0):

How is the `Enhancer` class configured?

You may need to add this annotation at the class level:

`@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`